# npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead

Tags: ios

I have the following error when update cordova on my mac

npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead

How i can update ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
npm uninstall --save node-uuid
npm install --save uuid
```